# Auto fill update form

Tags: django

I have a date model and a Order model. The date model is connected to Order model by a foreignkey, I'm trying to update the date model feilds in Order model  with a form. I want the form to autofill the fields with saved data in admin database. I tried a lot to find the solution but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

In your view.

You need to edit the function

```
views.py
def orderDetailView(request, pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
    date_instance = order.date
    form  = DateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=date_instance)
    if form.is_valid()
        form.save()
        .....
        ....
    context = {
    'order': order, 'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "date_list.html", context)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216210/discussion-on-answer-by-cyroot-auto-fill-update-form).